# Conjecturing that all AP-GP mixed sequences are the first derivatives of a pure GP

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

I was studying some series which are mix of AP and GP as
$$(a+d)+(a+2d)r+(a+3d)r^2+......$$

An example could be, $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+.....$

If i took ${|x|}\lt1$, and
while calculating the sum of the series upto $\infty$ terms by multiplying the series with $x$ and getting the answer as $$\frac {1}{(1-x)^2}$$ I just realised this series is the first derivative of the following series,
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+.......$$

I tried this with all the examples in my book, all of them could be somehow reduced to the derivative of some GP.

So my final question is weather all AP-GP mixed sequences can be expressed as derivative of some GP. If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: What is wrong in my question?, why the downvote?

Comment: 1, 3, 6, 10, ... is neither arithmetic nor geometric, and not of the form in the start of the question. (Not the downvoter.)

Comment: @aschepler, you are right. I got this series when i was playing with the upper series, but it has the same property(integrate it and get a GP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be written as:
$$a(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots) + d(1 + 2r + 3r^2 + \cdots)$$
For $|r| < 1,$ this becomes:
$$\frac{a}{1-r} + d.\frac{d}{dr}(r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots)$$
$$=\frac{a}{1-r} + d\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)$$
In your case, you took $a=0$ and $d=1$ and got the derivative of a geometric sequence.

However in generality, it is not possible.

Comment: How did you get that it is not possible in general?

Comment: The derivative of any pure GP with a given first term and ratio $r$ will always be a constant multiple of $1/(1-r)^2.$ Therefore it is equal to a constant multiple of $1+2r+3r^2+4r^3+\cdots.$ If you set $a\neq 0$ you no longer have a constant multiple of $1+2r+3r^2+4r^3+\cdots.$